# lotus notes javamail issue while reading body

Tags: apache-camel, jakarta-mail, imap, lotus

Consider that I send the following text ["abc <20 spaces>        b"], without the quotes, as body of an email to IBM lotus notes mailbox.

Now I've an apache camel IMAP mail component which reads that email. What I'm seeing is that after reading the email body, the text is wrapping to

abc

b

rather than "abc                                                                        b", which is what I expect

Any clue will be helpful

Comment: What format are you sending it in?  What are the content type and content transfer encoding headers?

Comment: You need to eliminate some variables in this problem.  Can you read the message without Apache Camel?  Does it have the expected content?

Comment: @Bill Shannon Yes, I did use a test program to read email without using Camel and its still the same result

Comment: @Max
1) I'm not the sender of these emails
2) When I read it, Content-Type = text/plain

Comment: What program is being used to send the message?  It sounds like that program is changing the text of your message before sending it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create / read the mail. Square brackets in Notes mark so called "passthrough html". That means: everything inside the brackets will be rendered as html. 
Your posted text will be converted to html. As `<20 spaces>` is not a valid html tag it is simply rendered as linebreak.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about the bad sample data.

Here is the body of email what I see in the mailbox,
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*NACS           *ZZ*TOMHEISER      *160411*0846*U*00501*773181795*1*P*> 

and here what I see when I read it,
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*NACS           *ZZ*TOMHEISER


*160411*0846*U*00501*773181795*1*P*>

As you can see there is a line break after the word TOMHEISER

Comment: While debugging using test program, I could see '\r\n' introduced after TOMHEISER , not sure who is doing that

As a side note, I see 3 '\r\n' always precedes the body content